# React Redux - get user after login and auth token

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a rails API deployed on Heroku and I want to code the front using reactJS and redux, to learn this framework. Right now, I have a login page and a register page. The register page is working without redux (for now) and the login page use redux. When a user logged in, there is a token stored in sessionStorage, but I don't understand how I can access the user data (like username, email and more).

When the user logged in, he is redirected to /dashboard/:id page, and I want to make an API call using this :id, but I don't want to use url params to do that, I want to pass state/props between my login components and the dashboard components. And I don't know how to do that using react/redux.

Here is the login form code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  * as authActions from '../../actions/authActions';
import axios from 'axios';


class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {},
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
        this.props.actions.logInUser( { data: { user: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }}})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label"> Email </label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input type="email"
                                   name="email"
                                   value={this.state.email}
                                   onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                   className="input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label"> Mot de passe </label>
                        <div className="control">
                        <input type="password"
                               ref="password"
                               name="password"
                               value={this.state.password}
                               onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                               className="input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Signup" className="button is-primary" />
                    </div>
                    <Link to={{ pathname: '/register' }}>Inscription</Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Here is the authActions code :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthorizationToken from '../utils/setAuthorizationToken';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import * as types from './types';
import sessionApi from '../api/SessionApi';

export function loginSuccess() {
    return {
        type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS
    }
}


export function loginFailed() {
    return {
        type: types.LOG_IN_FAILED
    }
}

export function logInUser(credentials) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return sessionApi.login(credentials)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.data) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.authentication_token);
                    dispatch(loginSuccess());
                    browserHistory.push('/dashboard/' + response.data.id);
                } else {
                    dispatch(loginFailed());
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            })
    }
}
```

The dashboard component code right now :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import  * as authActions from '../../actions/authActions';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> Hello user </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

The sessions reducer code :

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';
import initialState from './initialState';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export default function sessionReducer(state = initialState.session, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
            return !!sessionStorage.jwt;
        case types.LOG_IN_FAILED:
            console.log('login failed');
            browserHistory.push('/login');
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the sessionApi with the API call :

```
import axios from 'axios';
class SessionApi {
    static login(credentials) {
        return axios.post('https://spendin-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sessions', credentials)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        });            
    }
}

export default SessionApi;
```

I want to pass the data that I received when I do the API call, like username, id, and more..

Thank you !

**EDIT**

The rootReducer :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; 
import session from './sessionReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    session,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `loginSuccess` take a data object parameter:

```
export function loginSuccess(userData) {
return {
    type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    payload: userData
    }
}
```

When you dispatch that action, pass in the data from your API call. Note, this assumes your API returns a userData object in the JSON payload, so you'll need modify it to match what your API returns:

```
if(response.data) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.authentication_token);
                dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data.userData));
```

Then in your reducer, put that data into the redux store:

```
case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
    return {
       ...state,
       userData: action.payload
    };
```

BTW your reducer doesn't look right. Two things I suggest:

1. Don't do anything with side effects (e.g. navigate to another page!!) in your reducer code. This will definitely cause unexpected behavior and bugs. Do anything with side effects in the action creator instead.
2. When modifying state in a reducer, always return a modified version of the state that was passed in. Having a reducer return a boolean is not the Redux pattern; though it might work if your reducer has only one value, it's going to confuse anyone who is used to reading Redux code. With the changes above obviously your state will no longer consist of a single boolean value.

To access user data in your dashboard component, wrap it in a call to `connect()`. Your new export will look something like this:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        const userData = state.sessionReducer.userData;
        return { userData };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

This assumes you have multiple reducers that you combined with `combineReducers`. Your dashboard component will then receive a `userData` prop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have a rootReducer that combine reducers (the code is in the question that I have edited), does I need to import sessionReducer in my dashboard component ? because I have an error "Cannot read property userData of undefined"

Comment: No, you would never import a reducer into a view component. It wouldn't be connected to the store, so its state would always be empty/ the default. It's probably not working because you named the reducer `session` in combineReducers, but the `mapStateToProps` code is expecdting `sessionReducer`. You'll have to rename one of them. Whenever you have problems with the output of `mapStateToProps`, `console.log(inspect(state))` is a good way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok I put a console.log(state) in the mapStateToProps and I have this result : `{sessionReducer: true}` does it is normal ? (I rename session for sessionReducer in the code, and in the api call I put response.data that return all user data) and I have this : `userData: undefined` when I console.log the props in dashboard components

Comment: I would expect the state to look like `{sessionReducer: { userData: { email: fromYourJson@email.com, id: 1234} }}` where the content of userData was what you passed in to `loginSuccess`. Sounds like you did not change the reducer code as I suggested. As you work through this, put console logs all throughout your code so you can understand what it is doing. I feel like I'm writing your code for you, which is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Sorry man, I looking in my side with many console.log what my code return, and I try to find an issue by my self, but sometimes it's really complicated to understand, for example, does I need to put this in my initialState : `userData: {}` ?

Comment: Think of it this way: You are writing both the code that puts stuff in the store, and the code that reads it back out. As long as those pieces of code are in sync, it will work. So if you put an empty object as userData in the store by default, then when you pull data out of userData you need to check inside userData for undefined contents. Or if you don't put userData in the initialState, your code can just check if userData is undefined. There's no right or wrong way in this case.